# Eclipse 4 RCP How to launch another plug in in a new window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an e4 RCP which needs all the screen real estate. I have developed a second RCP that is in effect a relatively simple single-function plug-in, with currently only one part. I want the user to be able to launch the second from the first, then terminate it, all on demand.

As I understand it,  I have 3 options:

1. Launch a new workbench for the second, written as a plug-in. I assume this uses more resources and also has the problem that I need to track and distinguish events which will go to both.
2. Write the second as a model fragment plug-in that extends the first. This has the advantage that I can keep on adding to the second plug-in by declaration in the model editor. However, I believe this requires attaching to an existing container in the main model. I could add a new container to the main model and write code to flip containers in and out but it is all done in the model editor currently, and more importantly the functions carried out by the second plug-in are quite different from those of the first (main) RCP, so I fear the user will find the UI change confusing.
3. Use EModelService and write code to create a new TrimmedWindow and then child PartStack, and Part, and all the Handlers. I have not yet found enough documentation to fully understand the implications, advantages and disadvantages of this - aside from the obvious ones that the former declarations now have to be programmed and coupling is tighter.

It looks to me like Eclipse itself uses approach 1 for two of its menu items:

- Help Contents
- Eclipse Marketplace

From the UI perspective, the kind of UI separation of functions that I want to achieve is very much like these two items. Hence I am leaning to option 1.

Any corrections or alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly use a `PerspectiveStack` with two perspectives containing the windows for your two apps. The second app can be in model fragment.

You can then just use `EPartService.switchPerspective` to switch between them.

Comment: Thanks very much, Greg, for the very prompt reply. The second is really much smaller and focused on a single function so I think the Perspective switch would be confusing to the user. It's kind of a master-slave, which fits with the approach (I think) Eclipse takes with Help Contents and Marketplace.